# Enum object not defined when imported - Python 3 through Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 3 through Jupyter Notebook
I have two modules "color.py" and "painting.ipynb" in the same working directory.

**color.py**

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    BLUE = 2

def painting(color):
        if color == Color.RED:
            print("The painting is red")
        elif color == Color.BLUE:
            print("The painting is blue")
        else:
            raise ValueError("The painting is not blue nor red!")
```

**painting.ipynb**

```
import color 
color.painting(Color.RED)
```

When I try to run "painting.ipynb" in jupyter notebook, I have the following error.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import color
>         2 
>   ----> 3 color.painting(Color.RED)
>
> NameError: name 'Color' is not defined

I do not understand why I cannot access the color. Am I supposed to call the class ? It is the first time that I use jupyter notebook and Enum. Please help :) Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are importing the entire .py file; you'll need to refer to your "Color" enum with the following:

```
import color 
color.painting(color.Color.RED)
```

It might be better to import the bits you need individually depending on how frequently you plan to reference that Enum:

```
from color import Color
from color import painting
```

Comment: The `as painting` is not necessary, and I would recommend keeping `Color` capitalized (so no `as color`).

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Updated my comment.